# What am I missing here?

Tags: analysis, winning

```
[FEN ""]

1. e4 {0} e5 {8} 2. Nf3 {0} Nc6 {5} 3. Bc4 {0} Bc5 {3} 4. c3 {0} d6 {6} 5. O-O
{0} Nf6 {8} 6. d3 {0} O-O {1} 7. Re1 {0} Re8 {4} 8. b4 {0} Bb6 {19} 9. Qd2 {0}
d5 {12} 10. exd5 {0} Nxd5 {2} 11. d4 {0} e4 {20} 12. Bxd5 {0} exf3 {2} 13. Bxf3
{0} a5 {38} 14. Rxe8+ {0} Qxe8 {2} 15. b5 {0} Na7 {3} 16. a4 {0} c6 {2} 17.
bxc6 {0} bxc6 {0} 18. d5 {0} cxd5 {2} 19. Bxd5 {0} Rb8 {7} 20. h4 {0} Be6 {5} 21. Bxe6 {0} Qxe6 {1} 22. c4 {0} Qxc4 {8} 23. Bb2 {0} Qxh4 {15} 24. Be5 {0} Re8
{9} 25. g3 {0} Qb4 {7} 26. Bc3 {0} Qe4 {7} 27. Qb2 {0} Rd8 {26} 28. Na3 {0} Bc7
{46} 29. Bxg7 {0} Bxg3 {9} 30. fxg3 {0} Qe3+ {3} 31. Kh1 {0} Qf3+ {9} 32. Kh2 {
0} Re8 {4} 33. Ra2 {0} Qh5+ {13} 34. Kg2 {0} Qd5+ {10} 35. Kh2 {0} Qh5+ {1} 36.
Kg2 {0} Qd5+ {1} 37. Kh2 {0} Qh5+ {1} 1/2-1/2
```

In this painful game that I played as Black I know I could've won, but that's how most of my game are nowadays. Earlier I lost mainly due to blunders. but now I get to a winning position and then don't know what to do from there, and that is even more painful. So, from this game, can the error in my game play be pointed out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A possibility that jumps to mind instantly is 26..Qg4, with two threats:

1. Qxg3+
2. Re2 followed by either Rxf2 or Bxf2+.

The only move that prevents both these threats is 27.Kf1, but then black could e.g. play Qh3+ or Rd8. Both moves lead to an easy win.

In the position you obtained the most important thing is to make sure white can not solve a threat by developing a piece. As long as you keep that in mind and keep finding new threats and ways to use your pieces to their potential, you should be fine.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of Qh5+ Black would win by threatening mate with 32 ... Re1.  If 33 Qg2 Qh5+ 34 Qh3 Rh1+! 35 Kxh1 Qxh3+ wins easily because the wBg7 also falls.  If 33 Qb8+ Kxg7 34 Qb2+ f6 and White's out of checks (note 34 Qe5+ Rxe5 and 35 Qb7+ Qxb7).  Even on the last move 36 ... Re1 would win but there are a few more lines to check (find the mates after 37 g4 or 37 Kh3).